# how to return decimal values from python using for loop?

Tags: python

I want to print numbers 70 to 80 without using the numbers in code. So I decided to convert them from ASCII:

```
    for i in range(ord('F'),ord('Q')):
        print(ord('{}'.format(i))
```

but i get the error:

> TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Comment: Hint: just `print(i)`…

Answer (score 0):

avoid `the` after `in` and also just `print(i)` is ok to work perfectly cause the ascii value is represents your desired number like `70, 71, 72...,80`

Code should look like:

```
for i in range(ord('F'),ord('Q')):
    print(i)
```